# ¿ Como intercambiar toda una fila de un DataTable por otra?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tengo un Datatable con 4 columnas en el que hay rellenas 5 filas por lo que en total tengo 20 celdas rellenas.

¿ Como puedo entonces cambiar los datos de las 4 celdas  que hay en la fila 2 a la 4 y de lo que había en la 4 a la fila 2 ?

```
DataTable inicial:

   c1  c2  c3  c4
f1 d11 d12 d13 d14
f2 d21 d22 d23 d24
f3 d31 d32 d33 d34
f4 d41 d42 d43 d44
f5 d51 d52 d53 d54


DataTable final:

   c1  c2  c3  c4
f1 d11 d12 d13 d14
f2 d41 d42 d43 d44
f3 d31 d32 d33 d34
f4 d21 d22 d23 d24
f5 d51 d52 d53 d54
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos a modificar la property `ItemArray` de esta forma manipulamos a nivel de valores.

```
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  //Guardamos fila 2
   object[] row2 = dt.Rows[1].ItemArray;
 //Insertamos en la fila 2 ,el valor de la fila 4
  dt.Rows[1].ItemArray = dt.Rows[3].ItemArray;
  //Insertamos en la fila 2 ,el valor que guardamos de la fila 2
  dt.Rows[3].ItemArray = row2;
```

Comment: Lo he probado pero me salta una Exception en el dt.Rows.InsertAt(dt.Rows[3],1); con el mensaje 'Esta fila ya pertenece a esta tabla'

Comment: Perfecto, alli edito.

Comment: Ahora si ! funciona correctamente !!